# How to deal with the situation when the ExecutorService ThreadFactory returns a null instead of a thead

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I asked this question before but was unable to get it opened again as my update didn't kick of the reopen process. So resubmitting it

**My question is how to get an ExecutorService to realize that the thread is not valid(null) straight away without having to wait for the get on the future.**

I have a use case where when creating a thread in a ThreadFactory I want to return null if the Thread cannot be set up correctly(for example it cant connect to a server).

When the ExecutorService runs a submit on a callable and the ThreadFactory returns null as below the code will run but will wait at future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); and then throw a TimeoutException. The problem is that ThreadFactory.newThread() doesn't allow me to throw an exception here.

```
public class TestThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        // try to create a conneciton that fails 
        // I cannot throw an exception here, so if there is a problem I have to  return null
        return null;
    }
}

public class ExecutorServicePool {

    public static ExecutorService getService() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new TestThreadFactory());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = ExecutorServicePool.getService();

    Callable callable = new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "callable";
        }
    };

    Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callable);
    try {
        future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange pattern.  When would you _want_ to return null from a `ThreadFactory`?  What is the goal?

Comment: The Thread sets up a connection to a server when it's getting created. If the connection attempt fails then the thread should not be created and the threadpool needs to be informed of this. Should I be attempting this another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throw a [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) which feels like a sensible thing to do.

`RuntimeException`s are great for situations that are generally not recoverable. Not being able to connect to a database for example is a prime example of one of those situations. Basically in this scenario you want to say:

> "Something is really wrong and at the minute I can't process your
>   request. Try again later"

`RuntimeException`s can be thrown in method implementations even if the Interface does not declare them. So you can update your `ThreadFactory` implementation to throw a `RuntimeException` rather than returning null. You could even create a specific `RuntimeException` sub-class to ensure that it is clear what the error is within your application e.g. `FailedToInitialiseThreadException`

Comment: Yes this works. I was trying to throw a subclass of Exception before and this broke the ThreadFactory.newThread() signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom executor service by extending ThreadPoolExecutor and

override  methods where threadfactory is called to get new thread, to your need.